# Ansible: lineinfile keeps squashing my existing line instead of appending text to it

Tags: regex, linux, ansible

I've seen a couple of posts with similar issues and nothing appears to be working for me. Some mentioned the need to use groups in my regex so I've added them and still have issues. Others say just add 'backrefs: yes' to my lineinfile and that will take care of it, so far no luck.

Existing line:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
```

Expected Line after execution:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:/opt/somedir
```

Actual line after execution:

```
:/opt/somedir
```

My Ansible:

```
     - name: update ~/.bash_profile
       lineinfile:
         backup: yes
         backrefs: yes
         path: ~/.bash_profile
         regexp: '^(PATH=.*)$'
         line: ':/opt/somedir'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the backreference to the line that will be inserted.

For example:

```
- name: update ~/.bash_profile
  lineinfile:
    backup: yes
    backrefs: yes
    path: ~/.bash_profile
    regexp: '^(PATH=.*)$' # PATH=.* is inside group 1 because of the parentheses
    line: '\1:/opt/somedir' # group 1 can be referenced with \1
```

Comment: Thank you, adding '\1' to my line took care of it!